# What's the best way to create a .bik video converter with C#?

Tags: c#, video, converters

I'm trying to create a program in C# with Visual Studio that will allow me to convert common video files into a `.bik` (BINK video) format. The problem is, I've only worked in Unity and until this point, I've never made a custom program before.

Due to this, I'm unsure of how to go about this process. Normally with Unity, I can look through the API manual but I don't know if there's one for what I'm trying to achieve, so it's why I wanted to ask for help so I can get started.

Comment: Look at ffmpeg. I believe it can write Bink. There is a .NET wrapper library for it, or you can run its process directly and capture the output yourself.

Comment: @Llama I'm not sure how to go about that though. When I do research for ffmpeg, it talks about viewing .bik videos in VLC but I want to take a video file (like mp4 or flv) and convert them into a .bik video. The only program that appears online that can do this is RAD GAME tools, but that program is filled with malware and trojans, so I want to make a converter myself that I know is clean.

Comment: It looks like only converting FROM .bik to another codec is possible with ffmpeg. Since it's a proprietary format owned by RAD Game Tools, it seems like it might not be possible without their own software. Using the official download from their website, VirusTotal wasn't able to find any malware in the executable.

Comment: That's odd, because when I tried it with VirusTotal (both the URL and the file itself) it flagged both as malicious.

Comment: The SHA1 of the .7z file I downloaded from their website is E2964FB70D3F1B948B635EF2AB02D70B0130A654, which matches what their website says. [VirusTotal found no viruses in this file](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5cbef4053d000075ed5d7800d9c5ba9abbf4608f863246204eb49f2b28f4eef4/details) and, after extracting the EXE, VirusTotal [found no viruses](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/70f068ae6a663c86afced0df09113bfeceeba711ac9a62eeba4476c608bde127/details) in that either.  You are downloading from [Rad Game Tools](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm), right?

Comment: @Llama Yeah, this is the response I get when I try the URL:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/a0851ca1b710d8eb890d5261922fb483d43435a3a80fe9bba43f4576792b65e8

I also tried the file itself and while it previously showed as a trojan when I uploaded the file to the website, it's coming across as clean today for some reason:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5cbef4053d000075ed5d7800d9c5ba9abbf4608f863246204eb49f2b28f4eef4

Comment: Odd. Perhaps it was a false positive. My wife's laptop had one the other day that was flagged despite being a genuine EXE signed by both Microsoft and Intel.

Comment: @Llama I'm a bit worried, since this is my work computer and I don't want to risk it, however it's really important that I'm able to convert video files into .bik for my project.